# ARPACK error with eigenvector on igraph - python

Tags: python, igraph, arpack, complex-networks

I am recieving this error when I try to get the communities from somes Erdos graphs:

> InternalError: Error at d:\bld\python-igraph_1588168334861\work\vendor\build\igraph\igraph-0.9.0-pre+-msvc\src\arpack.c:1001: ARPACK error, Maximum number of iterations reached

I am creating the graphs and putting them in a list:

```
from igraph import *
    
probs=[0.002,0.005,0.01,0.02]

grafos_Erdos = []
for x in probs :
    grau_medio = 1000*x
    print ("Para o graqu médio :",grau_medio)
   
    for i in range(10):
        grafos_Erdos.append(Graph.Erdos_Renyi(1000,p=x,directed=False))
```

Then I try to get the communities:

```
for i in grafos_Erdos:
        a= i.community_leading_eigenvector()        
        c= i.modularity(a)
        print( "Modularity : ",c)
```

The firsts loops works, the error occurs after 9 full loops.

Comment: Try to set number of maximum iterations before looping: `arpack_options.maxiter=1000000`

Comment: Thanks my friend, this solved my problem !

Comment: If you can create a reproducible example (e.g. find a random seed that consistently reproduces this), please post it at https://igraph.discourse.group/ so it can be investigated further.